# ee.Image(Number) gets interpreted as float

Tags: google-earth-engine

I never encountered this error before, albeit working with bandmath on GEE for a while.

This is some Function converting DN to radiance. An `ee.Image` is created from a float value for example `LMAXlambda`

```
function radiance(Im){
var LMAXlamda = ee.Image(Im.get('RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_6'))
var LMINlamda = ee.Image(Im.get('RADIANCE_MINIMUM_BAND_6'))
var QCALMAX_BAND61 = ee.Image(255.0)             
var QCALMIN_BAND61 = ee.Image(1.0)          
print(LMAXlamda,'1')
return LMAXlamda.subtract(LMINlamda).multiply(Im).subtract(QCALMIN_BAND61)
            .divide(QCALMAX_BAND61.subtract(QCALMIN_BAND61)).add(LMINlamda)
```

}

following error is Obtained 
[image]
`print(LMAXlambda)` --> 15.303 ; but no ee.Image

i hope my Confusion is relateable

Answer (score 2):

its the Missing `ee.Number()` statement

with `var LMAXlamda = ee.Image(ee.Number(Im.get('RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_6')))`

its working